# Convert text from incoming message to hyperlink

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013

Outlook 2013
Our bugtracking system sends notifications where bug's ID is displayed as a plain text.

```
From:bugtracker
To:me
Subject: Bug 123456567 arrived
Message body:

Bug: 1234567
Description: Something went wrong blahblahblah
```

So I have to copy ID from the message, open browser, open bugtracker, input ID in the search box, press Enter.
This bugtracker is a 3rd party solution so it will take a long time to improve it on server's side (and I'm already pushing them for a long time).
That's pretty annoying so I would like to improve it a little bit on client's side.
I need to convert bug ID to hyperlink (like http://bugtracker/ID) somehow, so I can go directly to its location in bugtracker just in one click
After some research I think I will need to use Outlook rules.
Possible solutions I see:
1) Modify incoming message in-place/on-the-fly and convert bug's ID in subject (as outlook converts 'http' links or in message's body) to hyperlink - not sure whether it's possible at all and how to do it
2) Display pop-up notification with hyperlink - not sure whether it's possible at all and how to do it
3) Display MsgBox with "hyperlink" (as I understand it's not possible to use real hyperlinks in MsgBox, so it will be workaround with Shell command) - I'm working on this option right now.

Any suggestions on option1 and option2?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly found it's possible to realize option1
Solution is explained here - https://superuser.com/questions/464000/how-to-replace-text-in-the-body-of-an-incoming-message-with-a-hyperlink-in-outlo